# View values not returned to the controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, view

Can anyone tell whats wrong with my view? my model values is displayed correctly in my view but it is not returned to the controller action. public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(ClientModel contacts) my ClientModel is returned null.

View:

```
@model ContactManager.Models.ClientModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete Information";
}

<h2>Delete Information</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Details</legend>

    <div class="display-label">ID</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CanaClie0012.Client00130012)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Name</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Clientes0013.Nombre0013)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Contact Number</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CanaClie0012.Direcc0012)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Country</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CanaClie0012.F1Pais00200012)
    </div>

</fieldset>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
}
```

Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(ClientModel contacts)
        {
            contacts.Clientes0013.Client0013 = contacts.CanaClie0012.Client00130012;
            contacts.Clientes0013.F1Pais00200013 = contacts.CanaClie0012.F1Pais00200012;
            Clientes0013 clientes0013 = db.Clientes0013.Find(contacts.Clientes0013.Client0013, contacts.Clientes0013.F1Pais00200013);
            db.Clientes0013.Remove(clientes0013);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: In addition to the below mentioned answer - Did you try like this `@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, null ))`

Comment: @PankajGarg that's a good suggestion, but I don't think it should be necessary, been using `@using (Html.BeginForm())` forever and it works. I think there might be something else going on.

Comment: hi pankaj, model is still returned null. I cant see what im missing here.

Comment: @rcadaoas : Try placing the complete `FieldSet` section inside the `BeginForm`

Comment: Can you show me how to do that? @PankajGarg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Keep the helpers inside the Form like below.**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(i => i.PropertyName);
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

**2. In order to Submit the form and send the model in Post Action Method, you have to use a Hidden Field along with each DisplayFor Helper.**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(i => i.PropertyName);
    @Html.DisplayFor(i => i.PropertyName);
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

**3. You will not be able to see the Model values in Post Action Method when the View is like below..**

```
@Html.HiddenFor(i => i.PropertyName);
@Html.DisplayFor(i => i.PropertyName);
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, null))
{

    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but in either case he will still need to include the `@Html.HiddenFor()`

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using `DisplayFor` for all your properties. `DisplayFor` will not send anything in a POST, it doesn't create an input. 
You could add `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CanaClie0012.Client00130012)` , etc. to each one of your properties in order for your view to send anything back.

Comment: I added Hiddenfor for each of my field but the model is still returned null. I used displayfor for my other application and it works fine.